# PIG: How to remove '::' in the column name

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a pig relation like below:

FINAL= `{input_md5::type: chararray,input_md5::name: chararray,input_md5::id: long,input_md5::age: chararray,test_1:: type: chararray,test_2::name:chararray}`

I am trying to store all columns for `input_md5` relation to a hive table.
like all `input_md5::type: chararray,input_md5::name: chararray,input_md5::id: long,input_md5::age: chararray` not taking `test_1:: type: chararray,test_2::name:chararray`

is there any command in pig which filters only columns of `input_md5`.Something like below:

`STORE= FOREACH FINAL GENERATE all input_md5::type .`
I know that pig have :

`FOREACH FINAL GENERATE all input_md5::type as type` syntax, but i have many columns so I cannot use `as` in my code.

Because when i try:
`STORE= FOREACH FINAL GENERATE input_md5::type .. bus_input_md5::name;`

Pig throws an error:

`org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HCatException : 2007 : Invalid column position in partition schema : Expected column <type> at position 1, found column <input_md5::type>`

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved this issue , below is the fix:

Create a relation with some filter condition as below:

`DUMMY_RELATION= FILTER SOURCE_TABLE BY type== '';`  (I took a column named type ,this can be filtered by any column in the table , all that matters is we need its schema)

`FINAL_DATASET= UNION DUMMY_RELATION,SCHEMA_1,SCHEMA_2;`

(this new `DUMMY_RELATION`n should be placed 1st in the union)
Now you no more have `::` operator And your column names would match hive table's column names, provided your source table (to DUMMY_RELATION) and target table have same column order.

Thanks to myself :)

Comment: Struggling to understand  what you did, is it like this? **Problem**: you have a table, and you have the corresponding output, but can't write to it because the colunm names are wrong (have undesired prefixes). **Solution/Trick**: You take zero rows of the destination table and union your output data underneath it to give it the right column names. (**Warning/Why do I call it a trick**: This solution does not just strip the prefixes, but sets the column names, so if your columns are not in the right order you would get surprising results.)

Comment: @Dennis Jaheruddin, well this would work only if both column order matches in source and target.answer Updated .

Answer (score 2):

I implemented Neethu's example this way.  May have typos, but it shows how to implement this idea.

```
tableA = LOAD 'default.tableA' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
tableB = LOAD 'default.tableB' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();

--load empty table
finalTable = LOAD 'default.finalTable' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();

--example operations that end up with '::' in column names
g = group tableB by (id);
j = JOIN tableA by id LEFT, g by group;
result = foreach j generate tableA::id, tableA::col2, g::tableB;

--union empty finalTable and result
result2 = union finalTable, result;

--bob's your uncle
STORE result2 INTO 'finalTable' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer();
```

Thanks to Neethu!